# I need help computing $\int {\ln x\over 2-x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, polylogarithm

While integrating $\ln(\sec x)$, at one point I managed to break the integral into two. But I wasn't able to integrate one of those parts.

The integral I am having a difficulty with is:

$$\int {\ln x\over 2-x}\,dx$$

I am aware of the fact that this integral *cannot* be expressed with elementary functions. In fact, my educated guess is that the answer should contain a dilogarithm term.

I have integrated similar functions and used the dilogarithm (or even trilogarithm once), but in this case, I have no idea how to get on solving this integral.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: first step is to use Wolfram alpha, realise the answer is too complicated and conclude you went wrong somewhere else earlier on in question

Comment: No, this is how it *should* be. I just don't know how to get to that answer. Also, it's not a textbook question. I came up with this problem myself @Displayname

Comment: ohh okay, I assumed it was some textbook/assignment question and wondered why they'd give such a horrendous integral to compute...but I can't help you really but im sure someone will come along soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=2-2t$ and use $\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=-\text{Li}_2(x)+C$
$$\int {\ln x\over 2-x}dx=-\int \frac{\ln 2+\ln(1-t)}{t}dt=-\ln 2 \ln t +\text{Li}_2(t)+C$$

Comment: Thank you. How did I not come up with this on my own? Thank you once more!

Comment: Only, you forgot about a constant one half in the front I think. Other than that, the substitution works and is much easier than I thought

Comment: The intuition behind the substitution comes since $\frac{2-x}{2}=t$ works great with the denominator, but also $x=2(1-t)$ allows to get $\ln(1-t)$ separately.

Comment: I didn't forgot. Write as $\frac12\int \frac{\ln x}{\frac{2-x}{2}}dx$, do you see it better now? The $\frac12$ cancels with $-2$ from $dt$.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you ;) I forgot about differential

Answer (score 1):

If the power series for the dilogarithm function is easily recognized,
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\log(x)}{2-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int\frac{\log(2-y)}y\,\mathrm{d}y\tag1\\
&=-\log(2)\log(y)-\int\frac{\log\left(1-\frac y2\right)}y\,\mathrm{d}y\tag2\\
&=-\log(2)\log(y)+\int\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{y^{k-1}}{k2^k}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag3\\
&=-\log(2)\log(y)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{y^k}{k^22^k}+C\tag4\\[3pt]
&=-\log(2)\log(y)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac y2\right)+C\tag5\\[6pt]
&=-\log(2)\log(2-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2-x}2\right)+C\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x=2-y$
$(2)$: pull $-\int\frac{\log(2)}y\,\mathrm{d}y$ out front
$(3)$: apply the series for $\log\left(1-\frac y2\right)$
$(4)$: integrate the series, term by term
$(5)$: recognize the power series for $\operatorname{Li}_2$
$(6)$: undo the substitution from $(1)$